MIssing old package with jcenter closure
I noticed that the JCenter read-only repository has been closed. I currently have projects that made use of very old libraries (we're talking years...) and I can no longer retrieve them. I only learned about the permanent closure of Jcenter when I saw that the projects could no longer compile. Is there any way to restore these old libraries?
I tried putting mavenCentral in gradle in, but it doesn't find the necessary packages (for example, realm-gradle-plugin-7.0.8).
Thanks!

You need to look for other libraries that do the same thing your old ones did.

I'm surprised that this isn't getting so much attention. Has everyone already moved to Maven Central?

Some options you have:

Upgrade to a newer version of the library
Find a different library with the functionality
Make the maintainer of that library publish it to Maven Central (or Gradle Plugin Portal as it seems to be about a Gradle plugin)
Kindly ask the Gradle folks whether they still have their emergency JCenter mirror and could provide you the needed files
Get the library from JCenter and publish it elsewhere or include it in your build

The last point is currently still possible, today your build will succeed again as you just hit the last 24 hours tests-sunset before the final sunset: https://jfrog.com/blog/jcenter-sunset/
